# Unable to parse logs from log file in logstash

Tags: logstash

I am trying to get logs from log file in logstash This is my config file for logstash Please help me out with this.

input {

```
    tcp {
            port => 5022
            type => "syslog"
    }
    udp {
            port => 5022
            type => "syslog"
    }
    file {
            path => ["/var/log/haproxy.log"]
            type => "syslog"
            start_position => "beginning"
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
input 
  {
  file {
     path => "file-path"
  }
```